# Multiple Activities with the same activity:name

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

We would like to partition our intent filters to multiple separate activities of same name because on Android<12 if any of them intent filter domains fail validation then the entire activity is disabled from deeplinking.

This is how our AndroidManifest.xml looks like right now:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=<SomeString>
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application>
          <activity
                android:name="com.a.b.c.d"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:taskAffinity=<SomeString>
                android:exported="true">

           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.exampleA.com" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.exampleB.com" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried the following:

```
...

    <application>
          <activity
                android:name="com.a.b.c.d"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:taskAffinity=<SomeString>
                android:exported="true">

           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.exampleA.com" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.a.b.c.d"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:taskAffinity=<SomeString>
                android:exported="true">

           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.exampleB.com" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
...
```

The attempted partition returns the following error:

```
Error:
        Element activity#<...> at AndroidManifest.xml:50:9-88:20 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:9:9-48:20
```

I could try to make multiple activities that have the same workflow or yield to one activity but I am hoping to avoid that. Is there a possible way to overcome this error?

Comment: You could try an `<activity-alias>` for the second `<intent-filter>`.